Taiga UI select not working in angular 16
I have a problem when using select from taiga ui. The project uses Angular 16 and taiga ui 3.87ю
When opening the select the following error occurs
    ERROR Error: Portals cannot be used without TuiPortalHostComponent
    at get safeHost (taiga-ui-cdk-abstract.js:390:19)
    at TuiDropdownPortalService.add (taiga-ui-cdk-abstract.js:398:21)
    at TuiDropdownDirective.toggle (taiga-ui-core-directives-dropdown.js:109:56)
    at Object.next (taiga-ui-core-abstract.js:41:71)
    at ConsumerObserver.next (Subscriber.js:91:33)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:60:26)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at distinctUntilChanged.js:14:28
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)

I used the official documentation to install taiga ui and for used selecet.`
Project Dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@taiga-ui/cdk": "^3.87.0",
    "@taiga-ui/core": "^3.87.0",
    "@taiga-ui/icons": "^3.87.0",
    "@taiga-ui/kit": "^3.87.0",
    "@taiga-ui/styles": "^3.87.0",
    "@tinkoff/ng-dompurify": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "taiga-ui": "^3.87.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
 }

App.module
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TuiRootModule,
    TuiDialogModule,
    TuiAlertModule,
    TuiSelectModule,
    TuiDataListWrapperModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: TUI_SANITIZER, useClass: NgDompurifySanitizer}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Template with select
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
  <tui-select formControlName="testValue">
    <tui-data-list-wrapper
      *tuiDataList
      [items]="items"
    ></tui-data-list-wrapper>
  </tui-select>
</form>


Component with select

export class AppComponent {
  testForm = new FormGroup({
    testValue: new FormControl(),
  });

  items = ['1', '2'];
}


What could be the problem?

Have you tried, like, checking in the documentation what is TuiPortalHostComponent? And importing PortalModule as the documentation suggests?

To solve the problem you need to wrap the root-component in a <tui-root> tag
